# What am I doing wrong in my database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am frequently getting this SQL error when trying to run my code. What is wrong with my database?

Database code in Visual Studio 2012:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testtbl] 
(   
    [Id]   INT        NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [name] NCHAR (10) NULL    
);
```

The error is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   An explicit value for the identity column in table 'testtbl' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: when the error occured? during creation of the table or during insert into the created table??

Comment: The problem is in your code, not the table specification. You are inserting a duplicate key. Can you show us the code that is causing the problem please.

Comment: try it with `IDENTITY(1,1)`

Comment: @SufyanJabr `IDENTITY` defaults to `IDENTITY(1,1)`

Comment: @PeterSmith This error does not appear when inserting a duplicate key. It appears when attempting to insert into an auto increment column like `IDENTITY`

Answer (score 9):

Clearly you are trying to insert a value into `[Id]`. That field is `IDENTITY` which means the database generates it for you. Adjust your insert statement to exclude the `[Id]` column.